Resources to learn Germanic (Yekke) Haftarah trope
What are some useful resources to learn Germanic (Yekke) Haftarah trope?

Welcome to MY! This question has been edited to take out the "personal" which is one of the rules of this site. Please check out the site tour. We look forward to being of assistance, and learning with you in future.

Could this site be of any use? https://www.troptrainer.com/settings?tab=2
